# How to disable a special shortcut in Firefox?

Tags: windows, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

I've got a keyboard with special media keys for the calculator, e-mail, homepage and suspend mode. I already changed the behaviour of the keys in the windows registry, but if a Firefox window is in focus and I press the home page key, the active tab goes to the specified homepage instead of executing my defined command.

Is there a way to disable this behaviour of Firefox?

system info:
firefox 29.0.1 on windows 7

Answer (score 0):

You can use the restartless extension Customizable Shortcuts to change a keyboard-shortcut, wether it stems from Firefox itself or from an extension.
https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/customizable-shortcuts/

(linguistics) vowel mutation
http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/mutation

[image: Customizable Shortcuts/press a mutated vowel key to assign a predefinition to "None"]